# mysqldump of a database by a user with columnar priveleges

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to ignore certain fields of a table using mysqldump without creating a view?

Comment: i know you can ignore tables and choose certain rows, but I'd like to choose which columns to dump (or to not dump).

Comment: You can edit your own questions.

Comment: i know i can, but it felt more like an additional comments rather than a part of the question.

Comment: If you're elaborating on your question, then it's generally better to put all of the information in one place. There's almost no reason for you to "comment" on your own question unless you're maybe replying to another comment and want the reply to show up in their message box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with mysqldump. You probably want to use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

(and then you can use LOAD INFILE to restore it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: so that works for dumping tables quickly. But if I have to ignore a list of fields across tables in a database it get's messy. I also want to then pipe the result to a separate server and load it into a mysql db their.

Comment: i'll give it the check mark since it does correctly answer the question and I hate not giving it out. Thanks!